# UITableView Cells All Repeat 1st Cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView that was working fine until I added sections to it - now the data from the first cell repeats throughout all the other cells. When I remove the sections line below, everything goes back to normal.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSInteger sections = self.objects.count;

    return sections;
}
```

Any ideas on what could be going on here? My data source is Core Data, by the way.

**EDIT**

For `numberOfRows` I'm returning 1.

Here's how I'm implementing the cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Item *p = [[[ItemStore defaultStore] allItems]
                                objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    ItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];

    [cell setController:self];
    [cell setTableView:tableView];

    [[cell nameLabel] setText:[p itemName]];
    [[cell serialNumberLabel] setText:[p serialNumber]];
    [[cell valueLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d", [p valueInDollars]]];

    [[cell thumbnailView] setImage:[p thumbnail]];


return cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you return for `numberOfRowsInSection:` and what code do you use to put content into each cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using

```
cell.textlabel.text = [self.objects objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

This would work in a table view with one section, as the row number will increase each time.
However, if you have multiple sections, the row number is reset back to 0 for the first row in each section.
Therefore, indexPath.row will always return 0 in the cellforRowAtIndexPath method, hence you are getting the first object each time.
You will have to do a check for which section you are in, or even use the section number as a way of getting the correct object from the array.

EDIT: Looking at the code you've posted, this is exactly what's happening! Look into identifying which section you're in, and filling it appropriately.

Comment: I think you're right - see edit above for my `cellRowAtIndexPath` implementation. I'm adding the table rows dynamically, so which of your suggestions would you recommend for that?

Comment: You could try
    objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
instead of objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];.
I'm not at a mac right now, so I can't test to see, but that should work.

Comment: Yep, so you need to differentiate between the different "sections" of data. For instance you could have two `NSArrays` within a parent array. Then get your data by doing `NSArray *sectionArray = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]` to get the SECTION'S array of row data then `NSArray *rowArray = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` to get the ROW data for the row you're on.

Comment: Oh my god, it worked! I was up until 4am last night trying to figure this out, I am so happy right now. Thanks Glenn and Thomas! :)

Comment: Glad it worked! Staying up to 4am, you'll definitely remember how to do this next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because of the way that the cells are reused in iOS.

Make sure you're setting all the available options within your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
// init cell etc...
cell.textLabel.text = @"Your dynamic text";
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor myColor];
// etc...

return cell;
```

Also as you're using core data make sure that you're selecting the right data from the NSArrays and NSDictionaries you may be using.

If this doesn't help please add some more info, including some code etc.

Comment: See edit above for my `cellRowAtIndexPath` implementation. As Glenn points out above, I'm pretty sure that I'm not grabbing the right data from Core Data (I'm just returning the same row over and over again, when I should be returning a section). Any tips on how to fix this?