# UITableView Cells Repeating First Cell

Tags: uitableview, swift

My TableView has been repeating the first cell and I had trouble figuring out the problem. I've searched around here and found a relevant thread ([UITableView Cells All Repeat 1st Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989077/uitableview-cells-all-repeat-1st-cell)).

I figured out that the problem was that I was not specifying the section in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I understand that I have to implement indexPath.section into my code, but I can't figure out how/where.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let entry = entries[indexPath.row]
    cell.entryTextView!.text = entry.bodyText
    cell.entryDayLabel!.text = entry.day
    cell.entryDateLabel!.text = entry.date

    return cell
}
```

Comment: how is your entries array divided into sections?

Comment: @rakeshbs like this: 

    entries = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as [Entry]

Comment: @rakeshbs which follows this code: fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "section", cacheName: nil)